# SQL server key violation due to case insesitivity

Tags: sql-server

I m having a table in which a primary key is there with 2 columns(CODE nvarchar,VALUE nvarchar).This table contains the values in the Key columns as (X8900,A) but when I try to insert a new value as (X8900,a) ,its giving error message “primary key violation”.

Why its giving this error,if case is different for values column and is there any solution for this in order avoid the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify if SQL Server should be **case sensitive** or not using **collation**.  In this instance the column must have a case sensitive collation in order for you to be able to specify any type of unique constraint on it.  For example, the **first example will fail** whereas the **second will work**, notice the CI and CS for case insensitive and sensitive.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
col1 varchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('ASD')
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('asd')

CREATE TABLE test2 (
col1 varchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('ASD')
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('asd')
```

Collation can be set at the column or database level.  If set at database level then all character columns without a collation specified adopt the database collation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the collation of your database. If you have a case insensitive collation, 'A' == 'a'. If you need to maintain difference between cases, you can either change the collation to a case sensitive collation, or you could cast the strings to varbinary. A binary representation differentiates between cases.

Collations can be set at the server level (i.e what databases default to) and at the database level (overriding the server collation). At an even more granular level, you can set collation on individual columns if you want/need. Here are a few articles to look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx#TsqlProcedure
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Here are a few SQL snippets you can run to view your current server collation, as well as the default collations on each database

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));

SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;
```